# Apigeetool deploy error

Tags: apigee

I'm trying to deploy from apigee tool with the following command:

```
apigeetool deployproxy  -n my_proxy_name -o myorgname -e test -d apiproxy-3/ -b my_base_path -u myusername -p mypassword
```

and getting always this:

```
Import failed to /v1/organizations/myorg/apis?action=import&name=my_proxy_name with status 400:
{
  "code" : "messaging.config.beans.InvalidBundle",
   "message" : "Bundle is invalid. Unable to read/find APIProxy contents",
  "contexts" : [ ]
}
```

At first I thought it was my proxy development.. so I tried downloading the proxy as zip file, uncompressing it, and then uploading from this command without any changes, and got the same thing.

Could this be a problem with me being on yosemite dev build 2?

Comment: are you deploying from the apiproxy-3/ path? and your base path must start with an /.. does it?

Comment: apiproxy-3/ is the local path to the local directory where my proxy is. in it is the proxies, and targets directory and the xml descriptor of the proxy

Comment: I usually see that happening when the bundle path or basepath aren't correct. I haven't had any troubles deploying on Yosemite.

Comment: I don't understand why the downvote, just to update it seems the deploytool is also broken, listing proxies explodes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue here is with the paid hosted option, it seems My org was having an isse and support is looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the subdirectory from apiproxy-3 to apiproxy, then retry.